# Having someone recite a hesped for someone they didn’t know

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, funeral-burial-levaya, yoreh-deah, bein-adam-lachavero

Is there anything problematic in  Halacha with having somebody recite a hesped for somebody else if they didn’t know each other? Or is there nothing wrong with it? Does it make a difference if the person is a Talmid chacham, am Haaretz, etc.?

Comment: When my mother passed away, the man from the Sephardic _Chevra Qadisha_, that led the burial ceremony, wanted to give a _hesped_ for my mother, though he didn't know her personally, and most probably had never known _of_ her, until that day. I assume from this, that such practice is common, and acceptable (at least, among Sephardim in Israel). We (her family) asked that he didn't, and he cut that part of the service short.